# yii2 jasper on basic template

Tags: php, yii2, jasper-reports

I've followed step by step instructions from [JasperReports for yii2](https://github.com/chrmorandi/yii2-jasper).

1. Installed JDK 1.8 on my Debian 8
2. Setted up mysql connector's classpath in /etc/profile
3. Added chrmorandi/yii2-jasper to my composer and updated

I guess php exec() function is enabled because the following test in any view resolves successfuly ...

```
<? echo exec('whoami'); ?>
```

chromandi is now under /vendors

java -version says 1.8.0_111

$CLASHPATH points to /usr/share/mysql-connector-java/mysql-connector-java-5.1.40-bin.jar

configuration is so ...

```
'components' => [
    'jasper' => [
        'class' => 'chrmorandi\jasper',
        'db' => [
            'host' => 'localhost',
            'port' => 3306,
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'dbname' => 'acme',
            'username' => 'acme',
            'password' => 'acme'
        ]
    ],
    ...
]
```

I added a controller like this ...

```
<?php

namespace app\controllers;

use Yii;
use chrmorandi\Jasper;

class EstadisticasController extends \yii\web\Controller {

    public function actionIndex() {
        // Set alias for sample directory
        Yii::setAlias('example', '@vendor/chrmorandi/yii2-jasper/examples');

        /* @var $jasper Jasper */
        $jasper = Yii::$app->jasper;

        // Compile a JRXML to Jasper
        $jasper->compile(Yii::getAlias('@example') . '/hello_world.jrxml')->execute();

        // Process a Jasper file to PDF and RTF (you can use directly the .jrxml)
        $jasper->process(Yii::getAlias('@example') . '/hello_world.jasper', [
            'php_version' => 'xxx'
        ], [
            'pdf',
            'rtf'
        ], false, false)->execute();

        // List the parameters from a Jasper file.
        $array = $jasper->listParameters(Yii::getAlias('@example') . '/hello_world.jasper')->execute();

        // return pdf file
        Yii::$app->response->sendFile(Yii::getAlias('@example') . '/hello_world.pdf');

    }
}
```

and tested http://www.acme.es/estadisticas/index that is supposed to be a built-in example.

Now it comes the problem. It complains about

```
$jasper = Yii::$app->jasper;
```

line. The output says

> ReflectionException Class chrmorandi\jasper does not exist

Anyone facing this issue? There is no much info about jasper on Yii. Any help would be welcome. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally the solution was changing

```
$jasper = Yii::$app->jasper;
```

to

```
$jasper = new \chrmorandi\jasper\Jasper();
```

Don't know why in the yii2-jasper documentation is setted so if it does not work. Anyway you can make it work following my above compilation.

As the

```
use chrmorandi\Jasper
```

is not working properly

You will have to change Jasper.php setting in the init function this

```
$componentes = Yii::$app->components;
$this->db = $componentes['jasper']['db'];
```

to make it work.

Editing under vendors is not something I want to do. In order to prevent these fixes I moved from chrmorandi's extension (until its improvement) to [cossou/jasperphp](https://packagist.org/packages/cossou/jasperphp) extension.

So far the cossou's extension reaches all my goals.

I hope this helps somebody.